# Можно ли использовать один ключ Google API для нескольких доменов?

Tags: google-api

Один ключ Google API можно использовать только для одного домена, или его можно использовать и для нескольких доменов?

Answer (score 0):

> Один Google API ключ можно использовать только для одного домена или его можно использовать для нескольких доменов?

Это зависит от Ваших настроек ограничений для ключа в консоли. Вы можете использовать один ключ для нескольких доменов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Ограничения позволяют указать, какие веб-сайты, IP-адреса и приложения
>   смогут использовать этот ключ.